# Rewriting Path of static images in a dynamic way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a DB Table full of different domain names.  I would like to access images via http://www.MyDomain1.com/images/image.png

Rather than

http://www.MyDomain1.com/MyDomain1/Images/image.png

As it is being physically stored on the server.

I know I could use IIS 7.5 Re-Write - the issue is that the /MyDomain1/ part of the physical path needs to be populated dynamically.

Is there a way for me to run a query on each request that can grab the correct 'images' folder based on the domain, and then map requests so that I can access 'images' as I need to?

Comment: Not sure I understand the relevance of the db table. It holds the domain names? And you're say the images are stored by physically convention in `/{domain}/images/...`

Comment: Yes, it is dynbamically populating from the DB Table

Comment: This will answer your question http://maxivak.com/dynamic-url-rewriting-on-asp-net-mvc/